# What email headers are useful for determining if my email account has been compromised?

Tags: security, email, smtp, spam

I've recently received a lot of spam replies (automated replies from users, and rejections from mail servers) to a certain email address. I've taken the obvious precautions of changing passwords, and even my SSH keys used to access my web host (also hosts email). I've also wiped my machine with a fresh OS install twice over since this started.

Is there anything I can look at with these replies that might help me figure out whether someone is simply spoofing my email, or if the spamming is legitimately coming from my account? Are there any email headers that would help me tell the difference?

Comment: What sort of email account do you have? How do you access it?

Comment: Look for path of an email. Each mail server adds its own header where is who sent that email to it. If it was sent by your mail server there is the possibility of being compromised. If the mail server who sent the email looks shady it is spam